# Trying to unzip a file, 'Filename not matched' when the directory exists

Tags: linux, terminal, fedora, zip

While trying to unzip a file named `Joomla_3.0.3-Stable-Full_Package.zip` to the directory named `joomla` I get filename not matched. Why is that?

```
# unzip -Z Joomla_3.0.3-Stable-Full_Package.zip /opt/lampp/htdocs/joomla/  
Archive:  Joomla_3.0.3-Stable-Full_Package.zip  
caution: filename not matched:  /opt/lampp/htdocs/joomla/
```

Here is the screen cast of the directory:

[image: joomla screen cast]

(The joomla directory is empty)

Comment: i hit this error when i forgot to put a `-d` before my exdir argument

Answer (score 65):

You can also get this when trying to specify the files to unzip and using a wildcard character. For example:

```
unzip -o somearchive.zip somedir/*
```

What may happen is that bash expands `somedir/*` to an actual existing dir and the files it contains. That list is then passed to unzip and it tries to find these files in the zip file.

To prevent this behavior just escape the `*` like this:

```
unzip -o somearchive.zip somedir/\*
```

Or, put the files to extract in double quotes:

```
unzip -o somearchive.zip "somedir/*"
```

Comment: What's the -o  flag?

Comment: The -o option is to overwrite existing files without prompting.

Comment: You might also get the 'Filename not matched' error when your `-o` flag is in the wrong place: `unzip -o ARCHIVE_NAME.zip` is good while `unzip ARCHIVE_NAME.zip -o` is bad

Comment: Downvoting because, although this answer makes true statements, they don’t address the issue the OP has, which is a misunderstanding about that arguments to unzip.

Comment: Also commenting the solution is to add `-d` before the target directory, as in the answer below: https://superuser.com/a/563232/388883

Answer (score 48):

You will also get that error if you try to unzip a whole directory of zips with a single command, like:

```
unzip *.zip
```

I found the solution on another site. 
The `*` symbol must be escaped, so you should run this instead:

```
unzip \*.zip
```

instead.

Comment: oh.. looks like escape symbols arent allowed but im sure that everyone knows what those are.

Comment: This doesn’t make any sense to me, at least not if you’re talking about Unix / Linux.  (It might make sense if you’re talking about Windows, but this question is about Fedora Linux.)  And, to the extent that it does make sense (potentially), it appears to be a duplicate of [sjbotha’s answer](https://superuser.com/q/563215/354511#611480).  Can you explain what you mean more clearly?

Comment: i was talking about the unzip command that i used on a linux system. i had a directory with many zip files and i tried to extract them all with unzip *.zip and got that error because the * was not escaped. you might also be right about this not belonging here since the op just tried to extract one zip file and i was trying to extract many with one command.

Comment: This simplest answer is the best. And this is it. Thank you @dfasdfg

Comment: if I try to escape the `*` on my ubuntu system, it says it cannot find any zip files.

Comment: I don't know why the escaping is needed, but when I don't use it I get this:

`user@computer:/data/imputed$ unzip *.zip
Archive:  chr_10.zip
caution: filename not matched:  chr_11.zip
...`

works with it.

Answer (score 35):

The file name argument after the archive name specifies a file to extract. Use `-d` to specify the target directory:

```
Usage: unzip [-Z] [-opts[modifiers]] file[.zip] [list] [-x xlist] [-d exdir]
    ...
    -d  extract files into exdir
```

Moreover, `-Z` is used to querying the archive, not extracting.

Comment: didn't get you. Can you please write the command

Comment: @SuhailGupta: `unzip -d /opt/lampp/htdocs/joomla/ Joomla_3.0.3-Stable-Full_Package.zip`, i.e. drop `-Z`, add `-d`.

Answer (score 11):

This exact command worked for me:
`unzip -o archive.zip -d /Users/current/Dev/tools/`

Notice the combination of options `-o` & `-d` (destination/inflation path).

Comment: worked for me too.

Answer (score 3):

Use the -d operator

`unzip Joomla_3.0.3-Stable-Full_Package.zip -d /opt/lampp/htdocs/joomla`

Answer (score 1):

Trying to unzip a zipped file with a new name will raise the 'Filename not matches' exception. To workaround this move the zip file to the destination directory

```
mv the_file.zip somedir/
```

navigate to the destination directory

```
cd somedir/
```

from there run the unzip command without the destination filename argument

```
unzip the_file.zip
```

Everything will work well.

so in this case the commands should be

```
[root@Feddy Joomla]# mv Joomla_3.0.3-Stable-Full_Package.zip /opt/lampp/htdocs/joomla/
[root@Feddy Joomla]# cd /opt/lampp/htdocs/joomla/
[root@Feddy Joomla]/opt/lampp/htdocs/joomla# unzip Joomla_3.0.3-Stable-Full_Package.zip
```

Answer (score 0):

From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43777060/error-caution-filename-not-matched-unzip-command/69776501#69776501) answer:

The above error indicates that you used the unzip command wrongly. Your shell expands the command ‘unzip *.zip’ as follows:

```
unzip a.zip b.zip c.zip
```

The solution:

```
unzip '*.zip'
```

Doing this shell doesn’t recognize it’s a [wildcard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wildcard_character) character.